# prove problem if $m^2 | n^2, \text{then } m|n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

1. Prove that if $m^2 | n^2, \text{then } m|n$
2. if $m^2 | n^3, \text{then } m|n$? prove or disprove.

i really no idea of that, someone could help me?

Comment: Do you know the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, that every integer $n>1$ has a unique factorization as a product of primes?

Comment: @ulead86: Indeed it is, and that question has a couple of excellent answers, one using the fundamental theorem and the other avoiding it.

Comment: For $2$, set $m = 8$ and $n = 4$.

Comment: Or as addition to Andrew $m=a^3$, $n=a^2$ is for every $a>1$ a counterexample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1. there are a lot of proofs. This one is my Favorite
$$m^2|n^2 \implies  k = \frac{m^2}{n^2} = \left(\frac{m}{n}\right)^2 $$ 
But because only Integers have Integer roots, $\frac{m}{n}$ must be an Integer.

For 2. Let $a$ be an Integer greater than 1. set $m=a^3$ and $n=a^2$. We see 
$m^2 = a^6 = n^3$ so $m^3| n^2$ but $a^3$ is not a divisor of $a^2.$